# using json to to send php vars to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, foreach

I am after executing a mySql stored procedure in PHP. and then use a foreach loop to get the name and part1 and part2, from their columns of the table in the database. arrVal is what they are all initally stored in which I get after executing a stored procedure.

```
foreach ($arrVal as $key => $val) {
        $P1= $val['partOne'];
        $P2= $val['partTwo'];
        $nme= $val['name'];

    }//end foreach for task
    json_encode($nme);
    json_encode($P1);
    json_encode($P2");
```

if we for example go

```
echo "<br/>$nme"
```

we a result like

```
wow
new
cool
```

for each name

in the Javascript we have

```
window.onload = function addCalanderEvent( title, start, end)
{
 var eventName = <?php echo json_encode($nme) ?>;
 var eventstart = <?php echo json_encode($P1) ?>;
 var eventEnd = <?php echo json_encode($P2) ?>;

 alert("the event name is " +eventName +" start " + eventstart + " end " + eventEnd);}
```

I then use these variable for a function but all I can get is the one furthest down in the database base (last one from the foreach) example from the result above I get "cool" and the others are missed
thanks in advance all help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode a list of values and pass that to your javascript.

You should create a new array from "$arrVal" and put only the values you want to send to Javascript.

```
$jsData = [];
foreach ($arrVal as $key => $val) {
  $jsData[] = [
    "eventName" => $val["eventName"],
    "eventstart" => $val["eventstart"],
    "eventEnd" => $val["eventEnd"]
  ];
}
```

Then, in your Javascript, you could do:

```
window.onload = function addCalanderEvent( title, start, end) {
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($jsData) ?>;

  //you now have to iterate through the data array and do something with the values
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     alert("the event name is " +data[i].eventName +" start " + data[i].eventstart + " end " + data[i].eventEnd);}
  }
};
```

Comment: i keep getting the error in php
Notice: Undefined index: eventName in C:\wamp\www

Comment: You have to set those variables in PHP to whatever correspondences they have in the "arrVal" object. Could you paste an example of how "arrVal" looks? And where should the eventName, eventStart and eventEnd get their values from?

Comment: yea i had correspondences named wrong, changed eventName to name. there is no error but it dosent alert anything either

Comment: Can you put a var_dump in PHP on the $jsData object? Also, can you do in Javascript console.log(data); with data being the object from PHP. Just curious if you have the right data in both PHP and JS.

Comment: what is console.log? put it in and nothing happens. Var_dump has the arrays the I want anyway

Comment: If you open up the console (press F12 usually) you have a tab named "console" somewhere in there. You can do console.log(some_variable) and it will output the contents of that variable in the console you opened with F12.

Comment: window.onload = function addCalanderEvent( title, start, end)
{
  var data = [{"eventName":"WOW","eventstart":"2015-02-22","eventEnd":"2015-02-26"},{"eventName":"New","eventstart":"2015-02-16","eventEnd":"2015-02-21"}];

is what i can see in elements after pressing F12, still not full sure on the console.log. Thanks for all your help so far

Comment: Can you please check on the line with the "alert" instruction, at the end there is ");}". Please remove the } and make it only );   The } should not be there, must have been a copy-paste error. So the line should be: alert("the event name is " +data[i].eventName +" start " + data[i].eventstart + " end " + data[i].eventEnd);